# Pointer to a Qt Slot

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, signals-slots

i want to build a pointer to a Qt Slot:

```
union {
    void (*set_slot)(unsigned long value);
    void (*refresh_slot)(void);
} the_slot;
```

The slot definition is:

```
void set_pwm(unsigned long new_pwm);
```

I try to do something like this:

```
the_slot.set_slot = set_pwm;
```

But the compiler says that the signature does not match:

> error: argument of type `void
>   (DriverBoard::)(long unsigned
>   int)' does not match`void (*)(long
>   unsigned int)'

hint: the slot is in class DriverBoard

Any idea where my error is?

And if someone knows - is it possible to do something like that with signals also?

Thanks!
Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Slots and signals are identified by their names (when you do use `SLOT(set_pwm(unsigned long))` in your code, you are constructing a string). You can simply store the name and the object and then call the slot using `QMetaObject`.

You *can* use pointers to member functions in C++ (see the [C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/pointers-to-members.html)), but in this case I'd suggest to use Qt's meta object system.

Comment: Thanks! That makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from Lukáš Lalinský's answer, 'passing' signals and slots can be as simple as this:

```
  void Foo::bar(const QObject *sender, const QString &signal, 
    const QObject *receiver, const QString &slot)
  {
    // ...
    connect(sender, signal, receiver, slot);
    // ...
  }

  // ...
  fooObject->bar(aSender, SIGNAL(aSenderSignal(const QString &)), 
    aReceiver, SLOT(aReceiverSlot(const QString &))); 
  // ...
```

Comment: It's better to pass signal/slot names as `const char *`. The conversion to QString is not necessary.